# Github & Discord

Tags: github, discord

So I was hoping to ask for your input.

Currently I am working on a team where we have multiple repos, and multiple discord channels.

I know how to set up a single discord channel to receive notifications from a single repo using discords integrations.

But this is a little manual for multiple repos that maybe I would not be a part of. If possible I would prefer not to manually go in , create an integration, grab the web hook, go to the github repo, and configure it.

Do you think it would be possible to write a script to automate this? Just wanted to get some input from people much better than myself at this.

Thank you again and im sorry for the random question.

I manually went to discord, grabbed the webhook and set it up for one channel and one repo

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a webhook on each repository, you can enable webhooks for a organisation / teams:

0. Create a Github Organisation
1. Move all repository to the new Github Organisation
2. Navigate to Settings > Webhooks > Add webhook
3. Add and Configure Webhook